# error while working with ruby gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I recently installed a ruby based tooling using gem, and when I try to run the tools I get the following error. How do I resolve it ?

```
 Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/commander-4.1.2.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-02-17 00:00:00.000000000Z"
    /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- commander/user_interaction (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-0.93.19/lib/rhc/helpers.rb:1
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-0.93.19/lib/rhc-rest.rb:11
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-0.93.19/lib/rhc-common.rb:12
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-0.93.19/bin/rhc:7
        from /usr/local/bin/rhc:19:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/rhc:19
```

I installed commander as per the answer below, and when I try to run now it gives me the following error -

```
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/commander-4.1.2.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-02-17 00:00:00.000000000Z"
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- commander/user_interaction (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-0.93.19/lib/rhc/helpers.rb:1
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-0.93.19/lib/rhc-rest.rb:11
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-0.93.19/lib/rhc-common.rb:12
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-0.93.19/bin/rhc:7
    from /usr/local/bin/rhc:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/rhc:19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, You are using [commander](https://github.com/visionmedia/commander/) gem. Please install it by

```
gem install commander
```

Version is 4.1.1

Comment: Shamith thanks, however I am trying to now install ruby through rvm. It seems the installation is meesed up.